# "score" variable not updating, always prints 10

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from random import randint
import random
from time import sleep
a = 'circle'
b = 'website'
c = 'parallel'
d = 'purple'
e = 'picture'
f = 'professional'
g = 'hospital'
h = 'complex'
i = 'helicopter'
j = 'airport'
k = 'programer'
l = 'attachment'
m = 'python'
n = 'wireless'
o = 'spouse'
p = 'desktop'
az=randint(1,16)
zz=1
score=10
aa=list(a)
print "Welcome to Josh Azrin's word game! I will give you a scrambled word."
print "If you get the word right you get 10 points. If not than you lose 2 points. You start out with 10 points."
moo = raw_input("Are you Ready? : ")
print"Here is your first scrambled word."
sleep(1.5)
while az == 1:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(a,len(a))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == a:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
```

## ................................................

```
while az == 2:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(b,len(b))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == b:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 3:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(c,len(c))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == c:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 4:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(d,len(d))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == d:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 5:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(e,len(e))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == e:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 6:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(f,len(f))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == f:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 7:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(g,len(g))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == g:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 8:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(h,len(h))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == h:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 9:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(i,len(i))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == i:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 10:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(j,len(j))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == j:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 11:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(k,len(k))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == k:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 12:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(l,len(l))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == l:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 13:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(m,len(m))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == m:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 14:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(n,len(n))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == n:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 15:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(o,len(o))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == o:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 16:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(p,len(p))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == p:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 17:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(q,len(q))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == q:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 18:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(r,len(r))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == r:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 19:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(s,len(s))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == s:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
while az == 20:
    print " "
    print(''.join(random.sample(t,len(t))))
    print " "
    info = raw_input(": ")
    if info == t:
        sleep(1)
        print "Nice job. You just earned 10 points! Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score+10
        print score
        az=randint(1,16)
    else:
        print " "
        print "Nice try. You just lost 2 points. Please try agian."
        print "Your score is"
        sleep(1)
        score - 2
        print score
        sleep(1)
```

What Can I do to make the score counter work? I messed around with a ton and no matter what it stays at 10...

Comment: There's a principle of software design called "DRY", for "Don't Repeat Yourself".  If you find that you're repeating a lot of code with only minor changes, that's a sign that you need to wrap the common behaviour into a different structure (function, class, whatever.)  You should learn about Python lists, and about how `for` and `while` loops really work.  It'll make your life a *lot* easier, and reduce the code size  by a factor of ~20.   Beginners often make this mistake: did it myself long ago, and wrote a text game in elementary school with hundreds of `if command == "DROP BOOK"` lines..

Answer (score 2):

you need to actually reassign the value of score.

`score = score+10` not `score+10`

Simply saying `score+10` doesn't modify the `score` variable.

---

As an aside, there are a lot of other issues with your code.

1. since you're not looping, a `while` statement is not appropriate for testing which number was picked. You should be using an `if` statement.
2. There is absolutely no reason, and it makes your code almost unreadable, to have 20 `while` (or `if`) statements in a row. You should figure out a way to make a function that generalizes each case.
3. Why do you you have `sleep` statements everywhere?
4. you only have 16 possible choices but you're testing up to 20
5. it's better to avoid hardcoding where possible, as in `random(1,16)`.

Comment: Thank you. The reason why there is unasasary code is because its still under construction.

Comment: @user1970995 ok. You should mark it as the answer by clicking the checkmark if it helps you (you're a new user so I don't know if you know how)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `score + 10` or `score - 3` use `score = score + 10` or `score = score - 3`.
score + 10 just adds the value of score plus 10. It doesn't change score's value.